# Diophantine equations and complexity classes

Tags: reference-request

LINEAR DIOPHANTINE EQUATIONS 
(given natural numbers $a, b, c$, are there natural numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax + by + c = 0$?) are solvable in polynomial time.

QUADRATIC DIOPHANTINE EQUATIONS ($ax^2 + by + c = 0$) are NP-complete ([NP-complete decision problems for quadratic polynomials](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=803627)).

General DIOPHANTINE EQUATIONS are undecidable (Davis-Putnam-Robinson-Matiyasevich theorem).

> Are there other classes of Diophantine equations (with restrictions on their arguments/variables) that capture other complexity classes (in particular PSPACE) ?

Answer (score 4):

This paper, [Computational complexities of Diophantine equations with parameters](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0196677487900137) by Tung, proves co-NP-completeness of a variant with parameters over natural numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Note that it depends a lot on what set are you solving over.
For example, the NP-complete SUBSET-SUM problem can be considered as a LINEAR DIOPHANTNE EQUATION, when you restrict your solution over positive integers.
If you allow also negative solutions then it is solvable in polynomial time.
For an excellent survey, see:

[http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.114.3864][1]